# How to Generate Models using doctrine1.2 in an existing db with PHP?

Tags: php, doctrine

can someone please tell/type here how to generate models from an existing DB using php and doctrine ?, what i did was, I placed the Doctrine folder + Doctrine.php inside a folder named e.g  test , now within that test folder I added a php script named test1.php, and within that test1.php , here's the code that I used

```
include_once('Doctrine.php');
spl_autoload_register(array('Doctrine','autoload'));

$manager = Doctrine_Manager::getInstance();

$conn = Doctrine_Manager::connection('mysql://usr:password@localhost/dbname','doctrine');

Doctrine::generateModelsFromDb('/models',
    array('doctrine'),
    array('classPrefix'=>'Square_Model_')
  );
```

then nothing happend when I ran that script via cmd via php - f test1.php , what should I do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it is generating the models but not putting them where you think it should be.

`'/models'` will create a `models` directory at your filesystem root (for example, `C:\models` if you're on Windows).

`'models'` (without the slash) will create the `models` directory in the same directory as your script.

Comment: my question was posted 10 days ago. nobody answered, I was able to solve it myself..but thanks for your answer man :)